# Error - Compiling Gnuplot on Windows 7 using nmake and makefile.nt

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, dll, open-source, gnuplot

**Gnuplot experts or anyone who is willing to help me - I have explained what I have done in very simple words and in a detailed manner. Thanks for your time and patience in advance.**

My aim is to develop a new feature in Gnuplot by adding a new terminal to it. I did the following steps in the order mentioned

1. I formatted my system and reinstalled Windows 7. (no antivirus installed)
2. Installed Visual Studio 2008
3. Downloaded the source code of Gnuplot

Now, am supposed to set up the compiling environment for Gnuplot in Windows. So, I did the following steps as per the instructions in "README" and "INSTALL" files in the source code package.

1. Opened up Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt
2. changed directory to the "src" folder in the source code
3. Then I ran the nmake tool (the make tool meant for Visual Studio) using the file makefile.nt (which is for Windows)

> nmake -f C:\Users.........\config\makefile.nt

1. It compiled successfully and gave the wgnuplot.exe and gnuplot.exe files as output. Also the manifest files were created. (Note: I have not changed any piece of code from the original source code package)
2. When I tried to open the exe file generated from the compilation, it threw me this error

> The program can't start because MSVCR90.DLL is missing from your computer. Try re-installing the program to fix this problem.

This MSVCR90.dll should be installed already when Visual Studio was installed. I checked the `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90...` folder and the MSVCR90.DLL was alread there. Then, I tried 2 things to solve this -

- **Anything to do with PATH variable?** I made the PATH variable point to that directory. It threw me a new error that says

> Microsoft Visual C++ Library. Run time error. R6034. Here is the **[detailed picture](https://wiki.bentleypublishers.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442725)** of the error

- So, I reset my path variable back to the old value and followed the steps in **[THIS FORUM POST](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/82c9a143-4a45-4489-8118-4abbf1fcd111/)** to fix the missing dll problem by copying the dll files to the `C:\Windows\system32` folder. Again it threw me the **[same run time error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/82c9a143-4a45-4489-8118-4abbf1fcd111/)**

> AM STUCK AT THIS POINT. Please advise me on how to rectify this
>   problem. THANKS A MILLION :) Advance thanks to you :)

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use VS2008. If not Id recommand to use the current VC release. Your problem looks like some sort of version mismatch/incompablilty issue to me ...

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2010. It compiled and worked like a charm! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you need to use VS2008?

If not I'd recommend to use the current VC release.

Your problem looks like some sort of version mismatch/incompablilty issue to me ...